# Spring ignoring @Profile annotation when coupled with @Aspect on a component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I was having an issue of `@Profile` not taking effect on aspects annotated with `@Aspect`. Even if my spring profile is not activated the aspect will always be called, I have looked at multiple sources as below which seems to claim `@Profile` and `@Aspect` should allow to enable or disable the aspect based on the profile activation.

http://city81.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-spring-profile-with.html

[using Spring @Profile in @Aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310408/using-spring-profile-in-aspect)

Below is my code;

**DummyAspect**

```
@Component
@Profile("sdfkljklf")
@Aspect
public class DummyAspect implements InitializingBean {
    public DummyAspect() {
        System.out.println("Constructor: " + getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterpropertiesSet: " + getClass().getName());
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * spring.desai.common.repository.*.*(..))")
    public void pointcut() {
    }

    @Before("pointcut()")
    public void beforeMethod(final JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("Entering: " + jp.toLongString());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "pointcut()", returning = "retValue")
    public void afterMethod(final JoinPoint jp, Object retValue) {
        System.out.println("Exiting " + jp.toLongString());
    }
}
```

As per my understanding this aspect should only be initialised and applied if the profile `sdfkljklf` is activated. Yet whenever any of my eligible repository methods are invoked I can see the system out entries from the aspect in the console. It is a spring boot app so I can see the following in the which says profile `sdfkljklf` isn't activated.

```
2017-12-14 16:25:19,374 [INFO ] SpringBootApp : The following profiles are active: jdbc,embedded,rmiEnabled
```

Another interesting observation is that this aspect is not initialised at the app deploy time instead it is only ever initialised upon first call to the repository method. I found this out by placing system out logs in the constructor and in the afterPropertiesSet method. Below is the log excerpt from the when the app completes startup and then I call my rest endpoint which in  turn makes call to service -> repository -> database;

```
2017-12-14 16:27:48,325 [INFO ] TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-14 16:27:48,340 [INFO ] SpringBootApp : Started SpringBootApp in 5.13 seconds (JVM running for 5.611)
Dec 14, 2017 4:27:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-14 16:27:49,873 [INFO ] DispatcherServlet : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-12-14 16:27:49,891 [INFO ] DispatcherServlet : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms
2017-12-14 16:27:49,946 [INFO ] HomeController : returning home
2017-12-14 16:27:50,432 [WARN ] PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web-console/resources/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Constructor: dummy.pckg.DummyAspect
Entering: execution(public spring.desai.common.model.Persistable spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.BaseJdbcRepository.findById(java.lang.String))
Exiting execution(public spring.desai.common.model.Persistable spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.BaseJdbcRepository.findById(java.lang.String))
Entering: execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.SubjectRepositoryImpl.getSubjectsForStudentId(java.lang.String))
Exiting execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.SubjectRepositoryImpl.getSubjectsForStudentId(java.lang.String))
Entering: execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.PaymentRepositoryImpl.findByStudentId(java.lang.String))
Exiting execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.PaymentRepositoryImpl.findByStudentId(java.lang.String))
Entering: execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.ScholarshipRepositoryImpl.findByStudentId(java.lang.String))
Exiting execution(public java.util.Collection spring.desai.common.repository.impl.jdbc.ScholarshipRepositoryImpl.findByStudentId(java.lang.String))
```

There is no stacktrace as there is no error however I am unable to figure out what is causing it to ignore the `@Profile` annotation?

I have tried the following to no avail;

- Clean built the project
- restarted STS and clean built by manually deleting the target folder while restart.
- Changed the name of the aspect class to make sure it is not being initialised by any hard coded bean definition.
- placed it in a completely different package with different root to ensure it is not being scanned by any errant componentScan
- enabled DEBUG log on whole spring framework to see what is logged before this aspect is initialised however there is nothing that came close to the root cause.
- Autowired the application context in my rest controller and printed list of bean definition names via following code. However the aspect is not initialised at deploy so its not in there;

  ```
  for(String s : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {   
      System.out.println(s);
  }
  ```

I am using aspectj 1.8.6 with spring 4.3.2 and sprint-boot 1.4.0 on java 7. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If require any more details please let me know;

Comment: When stating _I am using aspectj x.y.z_ you should also add how do you use it. Are you using compile-time weaving? Load-time weaving with a java agent? Maybe LTW with classloaders?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class AopConfiguration {

    @Aspect
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    @Profile("my_profile")
    static class AopRule1 {

        @Around("/*some rules*/")
        public Object doAop(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //logic
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess here is that you properly managed to actually use aspectj instead of spring-aop (the two very different solutions are often conflated), but then, aspectj is a technology totally independent of spring and it's not gonna take into account spring specific annotations on profile selection. Spring's `@Profile` annotation might work with spring-aop, since spring itself is going to create the proxies around your spring beans for spring-aop to work, but with native aspectj that's not the case.

You'll need to do runtime tests in your advices in order to decide whether you want your aspect to be active or not, possibly setting a boolean flag to `true` in `afterPropertiesSet()`, and leaving the flag `false` by default, so that if the aspect is not configured by spring, it won't run.

Comment: Ok That makes sense, well sort of. So I understand that the behaviour is inline with native aspectj advice (correct terminology??) instead of spring-aop advice which can be controller with spring annotations such as `@Component` and `@Profile`. However how do I configure it so one takes precedent over the other (native aspectj instantiation)? Because all I did was follow the first link in my question and enabled advice using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` there are no xml configs or maven plugins or java agents for compile time weaving.

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is the annotation to enable support of AspectJ annotated aspects in spring-aop, but it's not native AspectJ. Spring AOP works with dynamic proxies around your bean classes and will only apply to spring managed beans. Native AspectJ on the other hand doesn't depend on spring, it works on any kind of object not just spring beans, and instead of dynamic proxies around the original code, it works by directly changing the bytecode of the original code either at build time or at load time through the aspectj java agent. You should figure out first which tech is in use.